# Decimal datatype precision in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

I want to know that in redshift maximum precision for decimal is 38, If i use decimal(38,20) will it work?? what are all the limitations using decimal?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Numeric_types201.html

Comment: I will look into that